selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session error on Jenkins run
[31morg.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.

(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/127.0.6533.99/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver assumes that Chrome has crashed.)
I am facing this issue when I run my automation on Jenkins.
I have added all chrome options but still facing the same issue.
My Driver class code
chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
                chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-gpu");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--httpKeepAliveTimeout");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,2000");
            default:
                System.out.println("\u001B[31m Could not match the browser set in the properties file.");


Any help will very appreciated!
